# getComputedStyle returns NULL in Firefox when trying to get value for "background", but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

SOLVED!!! Here is solution, just see what the problem was below.
Firefox automatically converts **rgba(126,47,182,0)** to **transparent**, so the solution is to keep it close to zero, but not zero like this **rgba(126,47,182,0.01)** And do *var background = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null).getPropertyValue("background-image")*;

CSS:

```
.header-menu--formats{
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126,47,182,0) 0%, rgba(126,47,182,0) 25%, rgba(249,71,157,0) 80%, rgba(249,71,157,0) 100%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="header-menu header-menu--formats">menu</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.header-menu');  
var background = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null).getPropertyValue("background");
console.log("BACKGROUND:", background);
```

This works perfectly fine in Google Chrome, but when I try to run it in Firefox *getComputedStyle* function return *null*. I tried getting other styles, it works, but not for *background*

Demo is here: [simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/brootle/0ok72drj/)

My goal is to get computed background for an element.
I need to get this value -> **backgroundImage: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 0%, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 25%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 80%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 100%)**

Answer (score 1):

Firefox returns `background` styles individually

To get your applied style you need the following code

```
var background = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
```

Or you can get all the styles referred to `background`

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.header-menu');  
var menustyle = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null);
for(var i in menustyle){
  if(i.indexOf("background")>-1){
    console.log(i + ": ", menustyle[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.header-menu--formats{
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126,47,182,0) 0%, rgba(126,47,182,0) 25%, rgba(249,71,157,0) 80%, rgba(249,71,157,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu header-menu--formats">menu</nav>
```

Check if it's firefox

```
var f = navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox");
if (f > -1) {
  console.log("Firefox");
```

Comment: Still it returns different values for Chrome and Firefox.... Chrome is correct -> backgroundImage:  linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 0%, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 25%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 80%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 100%) And Firefox -> backgroundImage:  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 25%, transparent 80%, transparent 100%) As you can see Firefox doesn't return rgba values...